# Try-except statement not working in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, try-except

I wrote a program with the function `convert_12_to_24` to convert 12hr time to 24hr time, however, the times were only defined in the program, and did not accept user input. I decided to upgrade the code by allowing the user to input a specific time for output and used a try-except statement to check for errors in user input.

```
def convert_12_to_24(hour,minute,meridiem):
    if (hour == 12) and (meridiem == 'PM'):
        print("12:" + str(minute))
    elif (hour == 12) and (meridiem == 'AM'):
        print("0:" + str(minute))
    elif (meridiem == 'PM'):
        hour_1 = int(hour) + 12
        print(str(hour_1) + ':' + str(minute))
    elif (meridiem == 'AM'):
        print(str(hour) + ":" + str(minute))

hour = input("Hour: ")
minute = input("Minute: ")
meridiem = input("AM or PM: ")

while True:

    try:
        convert_12_to_24(hour,minute,meridiem)
        break

    except:
        print("\n")
        print("Error, please input in the following manner: ")
        print("Hour: XX")
        print("Minute: XX")
        print("AM or PM: AM or PM")
```

However, when I run the code, the code doesn't rerun with an error, and the order of execution for the function conditionals is messed up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/11082165)

Comment: All of your inputs are before the loop.  If anything went wrong, it's just going to try to convert the same values again, and get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code:

> hour and minute should be converted to int type when asking user input

> If any of the conditions are not matching I am raising an error by returning 1/0 so the code falls back to except in try-except block.

```
def convert_12_to_24(hour,minute,meridiem):
    if (hour == 12) and (meridiem == 'PM'):
        print("12:" + str(minute))
    elif (hour == 12) and (meridiem == 'AM'):
        print("0:" + str(minute))
    elif (meridiem == 'PM'):
        hour_1 = int(hour) + 12
        print(str(hour_1) + ':' + str(minute))
    elif (meridiem == 'AM'):
        print(str(hour) + ":" + str(minute))
    else:
        return 1/0

hour = int(input("Hour: "))
minute = int(input("Minute: "))
meridiem = input("AM or PM: ")

while True:

    try:    
        convert_12_to_24(hour,minute,meridiem)
        break

    except:
        print("\n")
        print("Error, please input in the following manner: ")
        print("Hour: XX")
        print("Minute: XX")
        print("AM or PM: AM or PM")
        break
```